# How do I convert that mp4 to the same format as this ts?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

```
General
Complete name                            : D:/aaa.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 2.73 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 154 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 3 715 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:04
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:05

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 6 s 134 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 3 578 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 4 320 kb/s
Width                                    : 856 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Standard                                 : Component
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.290
Stream size                              : 2.62 MiB (96%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:04
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:05
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 6 s 154 ms
Source duration                          : 6 s 200 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 137 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 320 kb/s / 320 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 104 KiB (4%)
Source stream size                       : 104 KiB (4%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:04
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-09-04 09:49:05
mdhd_Duration                            : 6153
```

```
General
ID                                       : 1 (0x1)
Complete name                            : D:/bbb.ts
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 3.13 MiB
Duration                                 : 10 s 763 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 2 434 kb/s

Video
ID                                       : 256 (0x100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 10 s 780 ms
Width                                    : 1 080 pixels
Height                                   : 606 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 142
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=4 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=48 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=20 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00

Audio
ID                                       : 257 (0x101)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Format version                           : Version 4
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15-2
Duration                                 : 10 s 750 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -23 ms
```

I tried "ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac bbb.ts"

But the two converted ts, "-c copy" into a new mp4 cannot be played in the iPhone default player

I think my use of "ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac bbb.ts" is wrong,

The following is the filler text, do not look

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

since all you want to do is change the container, you just need to tell it to copy the actual audio/video without transcoding.

Something like this is what you need to run

`ffmpeg -i originalvideo.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy newconvertedoutputfile.ts`

Comment: The first thing I thought of was this, but the last few seconds(6 s 154 ms) could not be played on the iPhone after compositing


So, I suspect that the video encoding is inconsistent

Comment: well you can always do a transcode will lose some quality but it should polish off the format for iphones..